# How to modify and run SOQL query dynamically in swift/Objective-C SalesforceSDK 10.2.0?

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios

How Update with dynamic value in the Where clause from Swift/Objective-c coding in the below
'usersyncs.json' configuration.

'''
{
"syncName": "syncDownUser",
"syncType": "syncDown",
"soupName": "User",
"target": {"type":"soql", "query":"SELECT Id, Username, ContactId, AccountId, StateCode, RoleDevName__c, LastModifiedDate FROM User WHERE Id = '00524000007atW9AAI'"},
"options": {"mergeMode":"OVERWRITE"}
}

'''

In this soql query how can we append **WHERE** clause dynamically from internal code(Swift/Objective-C) while creation, insertion, fetch and update SOQL query?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated my explanation.